# order of adverbs and their effect on the meaning of sentece

Tags: adverbs, adverb-placement

Which order of adverbs is correct?

1. but **currently** our educational programme just overloads
2. but our educational programme **currently** just overloads

I think the second one is a little bit awkward. If both are correct please tell me if the meaning is different.

Here is the full context if it helps:

> Education system should prepare children for whatever lies ahead by
> improving their self-esteem, but our educational programme **currently
> just overloads** students with homework and does not improve their
> self-reliance.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to answer this is find out what currently means and substitute it in both sentences.

> 1. but *at the present time* our educational programme just overloads students

this meaning is obviously ambiguous, overloads what? the educational program or the student or both?

> 2. but our educational programme *at the present time* just overloads students

The meaning is clear in this sentence. The students are overloaded.

currently: adverb: at the present time: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/currently)